# Finding and removing orphaned links in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-ootb

Is there an out-of-the-box way in SharePoint Online to crawl through a collection of sites and find/remove orphaned links?

**Note**: Not looking for PowerShell commands or any external tools.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No. SharePoint's actually pretty decent about changing hard links to resources when the resource location changes, but there is no tool to crawl a site collection this way and check all links for validity. Sorry!